# How to deal with links internalization in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The code below does not work, the link just disappears

```
 <a th:text="#{login.signup}" href="/registration">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using thymeleaf's way of defining links, with:

```
th:href="@{/registration}"
```

[More here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)